# Karma test injected service

Tags: angular, http, service, karma-runner

I'm trying to test a component with injected service that contains a http post method. but when I run the test karma shows me the message below :

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of undefined**

this is my code :

**this is the save method that is invoked by the button and the method addUser that call the SignupService  addUser method:**

```
save() {
this.addUser();
this.onShowModal();


 }

  private addUser(){
  // Copy the form values over the product object values
  let user = Object.assign({}, this.customer, this.signUpForm.value);
  this.signUpService.addUser(user).subscribe((result) =>         this.onSaveComplete(result),
    (error: any) => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
   this.modalMessage = this.errorMessage


}
```

**and this is the SignupService addUser method :**

```
addUser (user : Customer){
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this.http.post(this.url,user,options)
  .map(this.extractResponseData)
  .do(data => console.log('Add user : ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
  .catch(this.handleError);

private handleError(error: Response) {
return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');}



 private extractResponseData(response: Response){
let body = response.json();
console.log(body.data);
return body.data || {};
```

}

**and finally this is my spec that handle the error:**

```
   it('should save the user submetted',() => {
   component.save();
   let signup = component.signUpForm;
   signup.get('firstName').setValue('BEN');
   signup.get('secondName').setValue('wis');
   signup.get('username').setValue('wiss013');
   signup.get('email').setValue('xz@gmail.com');
   signup.get('passwordMatch').get('password').setValue('wis');
   signup.get('passwordMatch').get('confirmPassword').setValue('wis');
   let show = component.showModal;
   expect(show).toBeTruthy();
 });
});
```

Any one can help me please ?!

Comment: If you test a component, mock a service then. If you test a service, mock an http request. Only one unit should be tested at once.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, But it still not working and giving the same error,  I think that my spec doesn't recognise the Response module in the ExtractResponseData function. these are the imported modules in the spec file  : `beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ SignUpComponent],
      imports: [FormsModule, BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule,
      ModalModule.forRoot(),HttpModule],
      providers : [SignUpService, Http, ConnectionBackend]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  })); `

Answer (score 0):

```
describe('Test you service', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [YOUR_SERVICE]
    });
  });

  it('hashCode should return correct hash code', inject([YOUR_SERVICE], (service: YOUR_SERVICE) => {
    ....
  }));
});
```